# Django-registration ajax post form

Tags: ajax, django, django-registration

registration and to make validations I will be submitting the form via Ajax.

I have checked other posts and tried some options, but the `csrf_token` gives a jscript error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The form is for login, and if data is entered ok, the form submits ok even with the error. But if the entered data is wrong, just does nothing.

```
$(document).on("submit", this.id, function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var frm     = e.target.id;
  var frmData = $("#"+frm).serialize();
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: '{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}',
     contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
     csrfmiddlewaretoken : '{% csrf_token %}',
     data: frmData,
     success: function(data)
      {
      console.log('success');
        },
     error: function (data) {
      console.log('error');}
   });
```

I also have the `csrf_token` tag in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
// ajax components
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    };
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
```

And what my form looked like:

```
<ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="settings">
    <form id="glucose_boundary_form" action="/glucose/goals" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ glucose_boundary_form.as_p }}
    </form>
    <button type="submit" id="glucose_goals">Submit</button>
</ul>
```

What a button click looked like

```
$('button#glucose_submit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'glucose/submit',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('form#glucose_form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("glucose_form").reset();
            }
        });
    });
```

EDIT:

Here is my login and registration view. Although I do not use ajax for registration. The form validation happens automatically for the login page. Hope they helps you see what I'm doing and how you might apply my answer.

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
from loginregistration.models import loginForm, registrationForm

# Login user method
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    form = loginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        user = form.login(request)
        if user:
            auth_login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')  # Redirect to a success page.
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})

# Logout user method
def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loginregistration.views.login'))  # Redirect to a success page.

# Register user method
def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    if request.method == 'POST':                    # If the form has been submitted...
        form = registrationForm(request.POST)       # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():                         # All validation rules pass
            first_name  = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name   = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            password    = form.cleaned_data['password']
            username    = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email       = form.cleaned_data['email']

            # Tries to create a new user and add them to the database
            try:
                User.objects.create_user(username, email=email, password=password, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
            except:
                #Add error
                return HttpResponseRedirect('#ERROR')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')  # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = registrationForm()  # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is my login template:

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="post" action="" id="login" class="container" 
        style="background-color: #FFFFFF; max-width: 450px; border-radius: 8px;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Login to Your Account</h1>
        <div class="form-group container" style="max-width: 300px;">
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            <a href="/register" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Create an account</a>
        </div><br>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.forms.login.id_username.focus();</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is my registration template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Create Account{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="post" action="" id="register" class="container " 
        style="background-color: #FFFFFF; max-width: 450px; border-radius: 8px;">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Register for an Account</h1>
        <b></b>
        <p style="text-align: center">WARNING: This is a prototype website for testing purposes only. For security reasons, do not use your real credentials!</p>
        <div class="form-group container" style="max-width: 300px;">
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create The Account</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.forms.register.id_firstName.focus();</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi I have removed the jscript error but, I guess the problem not catching errors is because of the django-registration app. Is there any way to get the errors ?

Comment: I'm not sure what error you are getting. But for the CSRF token issue my code should be error free

Comment: Yes the csrf is ok now. But I am not getting login-related errors. For example, bad username/bad pass. The ajax call always returns 'success'. Is there any way I can handle those errors ?

Comment: Yes, the ajax call will return success. What you can do is look for your specific error in the result you return to the ajax call. For example, you view that is called by the ajax call will return a dic of data. You can add a status string to that dic such as `{ Status : "Error", ... }`. Then in your ajax success body you can look for that like `if data["succes"] == "Error" ...`

Comment: Updated my answer with some code form my own login and registration. although I dont use ajax when registering. The errors will be raised on my fields without ajax.